# Flycheck eslint with Emacs

Tags: emacs, eslint, flycheck

I'm very new to Emacs and have been searching all day to add eslint to Flycheck.

When I run C-c !-v in a React project:

```
  javascript-eslint
    - major mode:  `help-mode' not supported
    - may enable:  Automatically disabled!
    - executable:  Found at /usr/local/bin/eslint
    - config file: missing
```

I want to use the config file for the root project. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to create a config file for eslint and then flycheck will automatically pick it up. Press `eslint init` in terminal to setup a config file for your project